# Perl & MySQL - How to get top 100 most frequently used field (containing a number) from column in table?

Tags: mysql, perl, frequency

I have a table with ~100,000 rows.

I am trying to print to screen the most frequently used "`type_num`" from a column.

So if 2362 appears 1000 times in the `type_num` column, that being the most used type, and 1234 is used 987 times and so on, I get a desc list of most freq used `type_num`'s.

No luck. Here is my newbie attempt:

```
 my $mostused = DBI->connect("$thedb","$user","$password") or die "Connection Error: $DBI::errstr\n";

  my $getfreq = $mostused->prepare(qq{SELECT `type_num` count(*) FROM `productstable` GROUP BY `type_num` ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 10}); ##just tested with 10

    $getfreq->execute() or die "Connection Error: $DBI::errstr\n";

    while(my ($type_num) = $getfreq->fetchrow_array()) {
    print qq~$type_num<br />~;
    }

    $getfreq->finish(); #not sure if correct
    $mostused->disconnect;  #not sure if correct
```

> Connection Error: You have an error in
>   your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'count(*) FROM `productstable`
>   GROUP BY `type_id` ORDER BY count(*)
>   DESC LIMIT 10' at line 1

The type_num's are a 1 to 5 digit number. (Using DBI and strict but this example is cleaned up.)
I have tried several variations and examples I found while searching here but, I am doing something wrong. please help.

Comment: Are you missing a comma?

Comment: @Timmy: that's an answer, not a comment :)

Comment: wasnt sure it was that trivial!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
SELECT `type_num` count(*) 
FROM `productstable` GROUP BY `type_num` 
ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 100
```

To

```
SELECT `type_num`, count(*) as cnt 
FROM `productstable` GROUP BY `type_num` 
ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 100
```

Comma after type_num + alias for `count(*)` to reuse in the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Trying `SELECT \`type_num\`, count(*) as cnt FROM \`productstable\` GROUP BY \`type_num\` ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 100` but, what do you mean by comma after + alias?

Comment: Got it! Just inserted another query in the loop! Thanks!